# Why is my custom block template applying to all blocks?

Tags: theming, blocks

I have a region on my home page called home_area_1. It contains several blocks. I want those blocks to be formatted in the same way, so I created a template called block--home-area-1.tpl.php. It is formatting those blocks correctly, but it's also being applied to blocks in other regions on the home page.

What am I doing wrong? I only want the blocks in this particular region to use this template.

I'm on Drupal 7.35, and am fairly new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656), it suggests the file name structure to be like *block--sidebar_first.tpl.php*.

**==EDITED==**

In my themename.info file I declared

```
regions[sidebar_first] = First Sidebar
```

Copied the core **block.tpl.php** file, renamed it to **block--sidebar_first.tpl.php**, added "BLOCK NAKO" text.

Then I Flushed Caches. The image below is the result.

[image]

As you can see the footer region blocks doesn't have the override that I only set for blocks within the sidebar first region.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means. My template IS named using that format - block--regionName.tpl.php.

Comment: Even changing the dashes to underscores doesn't help - it's still being applied to blocks in other regions.

Comment: I meant that based on Drupal's template naming suggestions. since your region is 'home_area_1', the file name you used w/c is 'block--home-area-1.tpl.php' isn't right. It should be 'block--home_area_1.tpl.php' so that it would only format blocks in that region.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the cache?

Comment: I also did an edit to my answer. You're welcome. Glad it's all working.